# How to call a page template in another page in php- Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

OK. I have  page template called "bannerpage.php". How do I call this page so that the contents of this page are displayed on the homepage.php

I know that most common templates that have associated template tags (i.e., , , , etc.), can be called but I don't know how to call a "non-standard" template like bannerpage.php in Wordpress.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `homepage.php` file add `include('bannerpage.php');`

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to choose your page template from the backend page.[image]

Or..You can also include it in home page by :

```
include('bannerpage.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get_template_part();

> Load a template part into a template (other than header, sidebar,
>   footer). Makes it easy for a theme to reuse sections of code and an
>   easy way for child themes to replace sections of their parent theme.

From [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)